# Context Filters Views Taxonomy Parent

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a taxonomy list like this.

```
- House
 --Large house
   --- Large white house
   --- Large green house
   --- Large pink house
 --Medium house
 --Small house
```

I have a view url that looks like this

```
<url>/categories/large-house
```

My contextual filter depth is set to 1. So when I go to the above URL it displays all the nodes that have Large house and Large house children attached. What I want to achieve is to exclude all nodes that are attached to the Large house parent term directly and display nodes that are attached to Large house children.

Under Filter Criteria I thought this would work. My thinking is display all nodes except the nodes that have parent term Large house.

```
(term) Taxonomy term: Parent term (!= 0)
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite tricky because the taxonomy system doesn't seem to like looking for children.  You might need to use Page Manager and the ctools context system to achieve this.

- Create a 'page' (url) at /categories/%term-id that has the term currently being viewed as a context
- Create a view pane that requires a context of parent term id which shows all nodes that have the taxonomy term subordinate to the parent term
- use the view pane in your 'page' and set the context to the term being viewed

There's a rather good example of a similar use case [here](https://drupalize.me/videos/basics-views-content-panes?p=1147) (watch the whole series, it's really good).